# Why we equalize the logarithms those with same bases?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

This is not an exam's question , I already have the answer.
I want to know why when we have the logarithm of something with the same base, we can equalize the things together.
Like here:
$\log_{10} x=\log_{10}y^2\quad$
So  $\quad x=y^2$
Why is this?

Answer (score 7):

This is because the logarithm function with a specific base is injective. For an injective function $f$, it holds that if $f(x) = f(y)$, then $x=y$.

You can prove this in many ways, for example that it is the inverse function of the exponential function.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know what the logarithm is?

$$
\log_{10}(x) = a \Leftrightarrow 10^x=a
$$

In other words, $\log_{10}(x)$ asks the question: What do I need to put into the exponent to get $10^{\log_{10}(x)}=x$

Thus, if you now look at
$$\log_{10}(x)=\log_{10}(y^2)$$

you need to ask these questions again. But, because $10^x$ or any other exponential function with a positive base is injective (that means, every y-value is uniquely in correspondence with a fitting x-value), these two questions get answered by the same number and thus
$$x=y^2$$ holds true.

Comment: We could also say that $\log$ is injective.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $x, y>0;$

$\log_{10} x=\log_{10}y^2;$

$\log_{10} x-\log_{10} y^2=0;$

$\log_{10} (x/y^2)=0;$

$\Rightarrow x/y^2=1.$

Answer (score 2):

The implication you mention is because $x=a^{\log_ax}$, therefore $\log_ay=\log_az$ implies $y=z$.

Comment: We could also say that $\log$ is injective.

Comment: @Teepeemm Injectivity of $\log_a$ is a restatement of the fact that $\log_ax=\log_ay$ implies $x=y$, and that was what I was asked to prove.